# MySQL: index used only when I select only primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have this table in MySQL:

```
Table: city
Columns: 
  ID int(11) AI PK 
  Name char(35) 
  CountryCode char(3) 
  District char(20) 
  Population int(11)
```

I want to use index when order by CountryCode so I created index on this column:

```
Index: CountryCode
Definition:
  Type BTREE 
  Unique No 
  Columns CountryCode
```

Why *EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT * FROM city ORDER BY CountryCode;* doesn't use index:

```
| id: 1 
| select type: SIMPLE 
| table: city 
| partitions: NULL
| type: ALL 
| possible_keys: NULL
| key: NULL
| key_len: NULL
| ref: NULL 
| rows: 4188 
| filtered: 100.00 
| Extra: Using filesort
```

and *EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT id FROM world.city ORDER BY CountryCode;* use index:

```
| id: 1
| select type: SIMPLE
| table: city
| partitions: NULL
| type: index
| possible_keys: NULL
| key: CountryCode
| key_len: 3
| ref: null
| rows: 4188
| filtered: 100.00
| Extra: Using index
```

How can I change this behaviour - that is add index usage in first example?

Comment: I wonder if the data doesn't fit into some buffer if you select everything and it resorts to filesort because of the size?

Comment: This is very small table (like ~10 entries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a problem.  The first query runs *faster* by *not* using the index.

First, let's dissect the second query.  Apparently you are using InnoDB.  That means that `INDEX(country_code)` is really `INDEX(country_code, id)`.  That is, the `PRIMARY KEY` is implicitly tacked onto any secondary key.  The second query only needs `country_code` and `id`, so it can be performed entirely in the index, as is indicated by `Using index`.  It read the index, in order, and delivered the results.  Very efficient.

Now, let's look at the first query.  This time you asked for `*`, not just `id`.  The rest of the fields are not in the index.  If it were to use the index (and you can test this with `... FROM city FORCE INDEX(CountryCode) ...`) it would have to do this:

1. Scan through the index -- this delivers the `ids` in order, but not the rest of `*`.
2. For each id, reach into the data for the rest of `*`.  This is costly, especially if the table cannot be fully cached.

If, instead, it did a "table scan" (which is what you are seeing), the code works like this:

1. Read the entire table into a tmp table.  (This will be `MEMORY` or `MyISAM` depending several criteria.)
2. Sort that tmp table (either in RAM on on disk).

The table scan + sort will *probably* be faster.

*Other notes*

If your cities are in the US, "Los Ranchos de Albuquerque", NM, is too long for the field.  For the world, consider the 87-char "Imeni 50-letiya (Pyat'desyatiletiya) Kazakhskoy Sovetskoy Sotsialisticheskoy Respubliki" in KZ.

Do not use `CHAR` for variable length strings (city, district); use `VARCHAR`; it will be more efficient in space and, hence, in speed.

Use `CHAR(3)` for the fixed-length `country_code`, but be sure to specify `CHARACTER SET ascii`.  If you use the default of utf8, it will take 9 bytes, not 3.

Comment: Use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` before and after those datatype changes; the diff will be striking.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. This city table is only example, I had this problem on quiet more complex table, so I used this one only to simplify my question

Comment: I hope what I said transfers to the 'real' table.  Otherwise, start over with another question.